# Настройка обновления через squid

Tags: squid, ubuntu

Необходимо настроить синаптик Ubuntu 10.04 для работы через прокси сервер squid c авторизацией.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо в файл `/etc/apt/apt.conf` прописать настройки прокси сервера:

```
Acqure::http::Proxy "http://домен\логин:пароль@айпи-прокси-сервера:порт";Acqure::::Proxy "true";
```

Домен, пароль, айпи-прокси-сервера, порт подставляете свои в зависимости от вашего прокси сервера, если аутентификация на сервере не нужна тогда пишем:

```
Acqure::http::Proxy "http://айпи-прокси-сервера:порт";Acqure::::Proxy "true";
```

Comment: `/etc/apt/apt.conf` прописал     Acqure::http::Proxy "http://user:111@192.168.0.1:3128Рерозитории всё равно недоступны!

Comment: Вторую строку тоже необходимо прописать.Acqure::::Proxy "true";